# How to compare an AC signal with a DC reference using a comparator?

Tags: comparator

[image]

To answer the title question, the only way I could think of is this but they don't seem to be working. The AC RMS voltage at the input is 33 V and the reference voltage at pin 3 is 2.6 V. Voltage at pin 4 is 2.2 V. The opamp output is always high even when I change the voltage 26 VAC. I wanted the opamp to go low when the voltage dropped below 30 VAC.

The reason for the large cap is that mains voltage comes in momentarily hence a protection Zener diode D2.

Comment: are you sure you need 1W power rating for R1 and R2? Sounds like plenty overkill. C1 is a bad idea – your signal at the positive terminal of C1 has a DC component, a frequency component at twice "LIVE" frequency, and higher harmonics. A solid amount of that AC will simply be shorted to ground through that (probably soon failing) capacitor. That is, unless the low impedance (equivalent to a resistor of around 300 Ω, on a quick head calc for 50 Hz grid) makes your voltage source break in.

Comment: but, to address a more pressing issue: There's no guaranteed relation between NEUTRAL and GND in your schematic (and 5V supply doesn't sound like you're using a floating battery). What if GND happens to be let's say 4V *above* NEUTRAL?

Comment: what is the voltage difference between `NEUTRAL` and `GND` ?

Comment: A potential transformer between mains and the input would be a lot safer.

Answer (score 1):

1. The MIC7221 is a comparator, not an op-amp.

> The AC RMS voltage at the input is 33 V ...

2. Your schematic shows only one connection between the mains circuit and the low-voltage circuit. Therefore there is no return path for your mains signal and the circuit should fail or operate intermittently. Be aware that you must treat your complete circuit as live as there is no isolation.

> ... and the reference voltage at pin 3 is 2.6 V.

3. R4 is not required and will skew the voltage set on the pot. Remove it.

> Voltage at pin 4 is 2.2 V. The AC RMS voltage at the input is 33 V ...

That means the voltage on C1 must be about 220 V DC (since you have a 100:1 divider). This conflicts with your 33 V reading.

If  your pin 3 and 4 readings are correct (V+ > V-) then the output should be high, T1 turn on and LED1 should light.

> I wanted the opamp to go low when the voltage dropped below 30 VAC.

Again, it's a comparator. If everything is wired correctly then set the input voltage to the required threshold value and adjust the pot until the output switches.

You need to fix the disconnect between the low-voltage circuit and neutral.

Comment: Thank you for the answeer. The schematic is just a rough idea of what i had simulated on LTspice but they did not work when i had it done. I then learned that the comparator should have its input pins reference to the same GND lines. 

The voltage readings at pin 3 and 4 are correct and the out is high reading 2.8v which is the voltage at the LED. I guess this was a bad idea. Would need to consider a different approach altogether.

Comment: Your post doesn't explain what the real problem you are trying to solve is. Your omission of the neutral - ground reference suggests that you are not aware that the "low-voltage" side of the circuit may be at mains potential and that this is dangerous. You might clarify this in your question too.

Comment: Did not seem to be the best idea. Initially it was intended to sense the voltage drop at the primary of a transformer when the secondary are shorted. The transformer being a MOT.

Comment: When secondary were shorted there would be a voltage drop at the primary which i was "hoping" to sense and that did not go as planned. Hence decided to work it out at the secondary, schematic http://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/how-to-set-reference-for-a-sine-wave-with-dc-supply/?action=dlattach;attach=466811;image

Answer (score 1):

Safety aside, if you have an RCD it will likely trigger as soon as the circuit is connected to AC, as the cap. Charges between live and earth rather than live and neutral.